# Expose inner properties of initialized object via dependancy property in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have class which derived from `Control` and it is inside of the `UserControl`. So my `UserControl` is connection layer for bindings and everything going on in `xaml`.

Code looks as such:

```
public partial class CombinedControl: UserControl{}
public class DerivedControl:   MainControl
{
    public int ExampleProp{get; set;}
}
```

What I want to do is to access MainControl properties in xaml. I have its instance in CombinedControl and I can expose the object itself via `DependancyProperty`.

```
public DerivedControl Instance
{
    get
    {
        return (DerivedControl)GetValue(InstanceProperty); 
    }
    set
    { 
       SetValue(InstanceProperty, value);   
    }
 }

public static readonly DependencyProperty InstanceProperty=
        DependencyProperty.Register("Instance", typeof(DerivedControl), typeof(CombinedControl));
```

**My goal**: `<NameSpaceName:CombinedControl Instance.ExampleProp = "10"/>`

**Question**: How to access and alter initialized object properties in xaml?

Comment: The typical aproach is to also expose the `ExampleProp` in the UserControl. In the UserControl's XAML you would bind the DerivedControl's ExampleProp to that of the UserControl instance.

Comment: Yes, that would be last resort for me unfortunately. As MainControl has over 100 properties and actually putting them all into the CombinedControl is not a way to go, that is why my goal here is to access properties via object itself. Note: MainControl is from 3rd party so I do not have the source of it. That is why I even use this derived model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't use normal element-/property-level syntax, you could use a Blend behavior to target the `Instance` property on your `CombinedControl` and set its `ExampleProp` property to whatever value you want. This requires adding a reference to System.Windows.Interactivity, which is part of the Blend SDK (which comes with Visual Studio). First is the main behavior:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

// Sets properties on targeted items via XAML.
public class SetPropertyBehavior : Behavior<FrameworkElement>
{
    // Name of the property we want to set on our target.
    public static DependencyProperty PropertyNameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "PropertyName", typeof( string ), typeof( SetPropertyBehavior ),
        new PropertyMetadata( OnTargetPropertyOrValueChanged ) );

    public string PropertyName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue( PropertyNameProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( PropertyNameProperty, value ); }
    }

    // Value of the property we want to set.
    public static DependencyProperty PropertyValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "PropertyValue", typeof( object ), typeof( SetPropertyBehavior ),
        new PropertyMetadata( OnTargetPropertyOrValueChanged ) );

    public object PropertyValue
    {
        get { return GetValue( PropertyValueProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( PropertyValueProperty, value ); }
    }

    // Target object that has the property we want to set. If this is null, the behavior's
    // associated object will be the target instead.
    public static DependencyProperty TargetProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register( "Target", typeof( object ), typeof( SetPropertyBehavior ),
        new PropertyMetadata( OnTargetPropertyOrValueChanged ) );

    public object Target
    {
        get { return GetValue( TargetProperty ); }
        set { SetValue( TargetProperty, value ); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        UpdateTargetProperty();
    }

    private static void OnTargetPropertyOrValueChanged( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        var behavior = d as SetPropertyBehavior;
        if( behavior != null )
            behavior.UpdateTargetProperty();
    }

    private void UpdateTargetProperty()
    {
        // Ensure we have a property name and target to work with.
        if( string.IsNullOrEmpty( this.PropertyName ) )
            return;

        var target = this.Target ?? this.AssociatedObject;
        if( target == null )
            return;

        // Make sure our property is actually on our target.
        var targetType = target.GetType();
        PropertyInfo propInfo = targetType.GetProperty( this.PropertyName,
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic );

        if( propInfo == null )
            return;

        // Try to convert the string from the XAML to a value the target property can store.
        TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter( propInfo.PropertyType );
        object propValue = null;
        try
        {
            if( converter.CanConvertFrom( this.PropertyValue.GetType() ) )
                propValue = converter.ConvertFrom( this.PropertyValue );
            else
                propValue = converter.ConvertFrom( this.PropertyValue.ToString() );
        }
        catch( Exception )
        {
            // Do whatever is appropriate in your case.
            propValue = null;
        }

        propInfo.SetValue( target, propValue );
    }
}
```

Then depending on where it makes most sense for you to set the value for `ExampleProp`, you would add the behavior via XAML. For example, if you added the behavior inside the XAML for your `CombinedControl`, it might look something like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="NameSpaceName.CombinedControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NameSpaceName"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             x:Name="Root">

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:SetPropertyBehavior Target="{Binding Instance, ElementName=Root}" PropertyName="ExampleProp" PropertyValue="10"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <!-- Rest of control here -->
</UserControl>
```

If you wanted to do it from the XAML of whatever parent is hosting your `CombinedControl`, you could something like this (using a basic WPF `Window` as an example):

```
<Window x:Class="NameSpaceName.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NameSpaceName"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:SetPropertyBehavior Target="{Binding Instance, ElementName=myCombinedControl}" PropertyName="ExampleProp" PropertyValue="10"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <Grid>
        <local:CombinedControl x:Name="myCombinedControl"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: DerivedControl is already created in xaml of CombinedControl meaning it already has an instance of DerivedClass, so I want to access that DerivedClass object properties. On the answer: That will create a new object which is not the one used in the UserControl itself, so it sets value to different instance which is not my intention. Thanks for the effort but I've already tried that.

Comment: @Carl Ahh gotcha. Please see my edit and see if that will help you out. The actual XAML is a little more verbose, but I think the behavior will get you where you want.

Comment: Thank you! We were thinking of going reflection way as well, unfortunately MainControl is from 3rd party, thus small changes on it would break our code on runtime. Again thanks so much for your effort! I will probably stick with this solution if we do not come up with something more solid in the near future :). Will mark it as an answer when we will solve the problem, as I want this question still be open for possible cleaner solutions :) Have a great weekend!